# Unable to plot under Channel Data (Scrolling) while running eeglabv4.5 on matlab

Tags: matlab, eeglab

I am new to eeg analysis and so the following the tutorial 'Swartz Center for COmputational Neuroscience'. I am running eeglabv4.5 on matlab (trail version). After loading the dataset it says to  select the top Plot menu item, Plot > Channel data (scroll) which should pop up the eegplot() scrolling data window.
But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error using matlab.graphics.Graphics/set The name 'Units' is not   an accessible property for an instance of class 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder'. while using plot and channel data scrolling
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloading eeglab15_0b version solves the issue.